# MoreLikeThis not returning 100% score rate in Lucene.Net when comparing the same document with each other

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, morelikethis

I don't know if I am calling Lucene.net correctly. I'm trying to call the MoreLikeThis function to compare a document to itself and I'm only getting a score of 0.3174651 where I think I should be getting a score of 1.0. Am I expecting the wrong expect?

This is my code:

```
                int docId = hits[i].Doc;
                var query2 = mlt.Like(docId);
                TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(100, true);
                searcher.Search(query2, collector);
                ScoreDoc[] hits2 = collector.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;
                var result = new List<string>();
                for (int k = 0; k < hits2.Length; k++)
                {
                    docId = hits2[k].Doc;
                    float score = hits2[k].Score;
                }
```

Am I doing something wrong please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you are doing wrong is thinking that Lucene scores are percentages.  They aren't.

Document scores for a query are to be used to compare the strength of matches within the context of that single query.  They are quite effective at sorting results, but they [are not percentages](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ScoresAsPercentages), and are not generally suitable for display to a user.

Comment: I'm new to this as well, so I want to make sure I'm understanding your response.  Do you mean to say that his score could correspond to a "perfect score", despite the number being vague?  So for instance, if a different doc that was unknown to me was compared and came back at .3111111, I would expect them to be very similar (based on this "scale")?

Comment: No, there is no perfect score.  The maximum score seen above is simply the score of the best result, nothing more.  Many elements factored into lucene scores can grow to be arbitrarily large, so there can be no clear maximum (perfect) score.  You would expect two documents with equal score to both be roughly equal in similarity to the query with respect to the current state of the index.  They may share absolutely nothing in common with each other.

Comment: Well right but given that you know two documents are exactly the same, could you not assume that the score between the two is the maximum score?

Comment: Not quite, no. MLT works by extracting a bunch of terms that would be the best to search for to construct a query to get the most relevant similar documents it can find. It isn't a diff. So, a document could be constructed that matches the querying document better than itself! That's largely academic though, even if you could make that assumption, what good does it do you? You can't assume a uniform score distribution, among other problems. Lucene's scoring is not intended to work that way (though you could always implement your own `Similarity`).